# Similar script font with specific upper case B, H and S

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to find a font similar to the script in this logotype. I haven't found a similar font on either WhatTheFont!, Identifont or WhatFontIs. I'm starting to suspect the original is actually handwritten, but as I'm updating the logotype I need a font that can be vectorized. 
[image: Unknown arced font over cute cottages]

The logotype belongs to the handicraft guild I belong to, [Botkyrka-Salem Hemslöjdsförening](http://www.botkyrka-salem-hemslojd.se/html/aktuellt.html).

The lower case letters almost match the font Canciller, but the upper case letters are all wrong. They seem to be closer to the fonts EF Ballantines Script or Roundhand.

Is there another font out there that has better likeness with the original script, with focus on the upper case B, S and H? The lower case is not as important.

Thanks!

Comment: You could always consider starting with an existing font that's close enough and editing the letter shapes yourself.

Comment: That is definitely handwritten, yes. You can see that every single letter that appears more than once has different shapes every time they appear. Nice handiwork, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is two of the fonts, you can use instead.

[Birds of Paradise](http://www.dafont.com/birds-of-paradise.font?text=Sem%20Har)

[image: Birds of paradise]

[Tagetts2](http://www.dafont.com/tagettes.font?text=Sem%20Har)

[image: Tagetts2]

It will be great, If you found this helpful.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: Tagettes is pretty close

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely right about it being hand-lettered. Look at the repeating characters: o, e a, m, l... no two letters are exactly the same.

I spent a few minutes looking through Script fonts on [veer.com](http://search.veer.com/?keyword=script&producttype=IMG,ILL,TYP&productType=TYP) and [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Ascript/fonts/) for something similar, these are the best I could find:

- [Harman Script](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ahmet-altun/harman/script/)

[image: Harman Script]

- [Salt and Spices](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontforecast/salt-spices-pro/)

[image: Salt & Spices Pro]

- [Artistelle](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/my-creative-land/aristelle/)

[image: Aristelle]

With a little more time spent digging I'm sure you could find something close.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: I think Harman script is pretty close, but not the same. The other two, not really.